# Alternative of Httpget() in ampscript exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Below is the code in which i am doing a httpget() and i am getting the result.

```
Set @testlookup = HTTPGet(Concat(@test_url, "&code=", @code, "&name_delimiter=|"), false, 1, @return_status)

@test_url --> url of another business unit
```

We implemented security in microsite in all the business units due to which httpget() is not working.

I want to know if there is an alternative to get the output without httpget().

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: More specifically, why can't what you're attempting be accomplished with a single microsite page?